# Error Grouping By Multiple Columns using CASE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Is it possible to group by multiple columns in a CASE statement? I get error "Incorrect syntax near ','." in below code...

```
SELECT
  CASE 
     WHEN Type = 'Test'
       THEN Description
     ELSE MAX([Description])                
  END AS 'Description'
GROUP BY
CASE
    WHEN Type = 'Test'
        THEN Description
    ELSE ''
END,
Type, Account, Structure
```

Comment: No, this syntax is invalid. Why doesn't `GROUP BY Type, Account, Structure, Description` work for you?

Comment: If 'Type' is a certain value then I want to GROUP differently

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that when `Type` has a certain value (`'Test'`), you want the `Structure` and `Description` columns to be considered for the grouping but otherwise to not use them at all. This is one way to do this:

```
GROUP BY
    Type, Account,
    CASE WHEN Type = 'Test' THEN Structure ELSE '' END, 
    CASE WHEN Type = 'Test' THEN Description ELSE '' END
```

The `''` should be a (any) constant expression that has the same datatype with `Structure` and `Description` respectively.

Alternatively, you could separate the 2 cases, which will give you more flexibility on adjusting the `SELECT` lists:

```
SELECT 
    ---
FROM
    ---
WHERE
    Type = 'Test'
GROUP BY
    Type, Account, Structure, Description

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    ---
FROM
    ---
WHERE
    (Type <> 'Test' OR Type IS NULL)
GROUP BY
    Type, Account ;
```

Comment: Issue with using this in my SELECT statement now. I get the error 'Description' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Use `CASE WHEN Type = 'Test' THEN Description ELSE '' END` instead.

Comment: Same error I'm afraid.

Comment: No, it can't be. Show us the exact query you used.

Comment: I updated my query in original post.

Comment: @k09 Erm...where exactly is the `FROM` in your new SQL query?

Comment: Thank you. it helped us.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(Description) as MAX_Description,a.Structure ,a.Description  
FROM (select ,CASE WHEN Type = 'Test' THEN Structure 
                   ELSE '' as Structure
              CASE WHEN Type = 'Test' THEN Description 
                   ELSE '' END as Description 
      from <Table_Name> ) a
GROUP BY a.Structure ,a.Description
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have an error in your select clause, which is why you are getting the message you mentioned in your comment.  When you are grouping, you can only reference aggregates of your data, or columns in your grouping set.  In your case statement that is determining your description, you are referencing a non-aggregated description.

Try just removing the case statement there, and taking the max(description) regardless of type. I think that might get you what you want; If it doesn't, you'll have to explain your data a little more, because what you are trying to do seems backwards.

Comment: When Type = 'Test' I group by Description. So my select query is ... SELECT Description... When Type = 'OtherValues' I DO NOT group by Description. So I need to max/min/sum Description.

Comment: Looks like it works fine without needing the CASE in the select statement as the GROUP is done logically before the SELECT... SELECT MAX(Description) AS 'Desc' 
FROM myTbl
GROUP BY
CASE
    WHEN Type = 'Test'
        THEN Description
    ELSE ''
END,
Type, Account, Structure